# How to split a path using StringTokenizer?

Tags: java

How to split a Path like `"/test/abc/xyz"` using `StringTokenizer`? I want to get the last value, here above path `"xyz"`.

Comment: Do you have to use StringTokennizer?

Comment: Don't use StringTokenizer. It's a legacy class (and has been for several versions of Java), meaning it shouldn't be used anymore. Use the split method of String instead

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use StringTokenizer.

```
String path = "/test/abc/xyz";
String xyz = "";           
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(path, "/");       
while (st.hasMoreElements())
    xyz = (String) st.nextElement();
```

But I thing you should use String.split

```
String path = "/test/abc/xyz";
String[] parts = path.split("/");
String xyz = parts[parts.length - 1];
```

You could also use a Scanner

```
String path = "/test/abc/xyz";
String xyz = "";
Scanner s = new Scanner(path);
s.useDelimiter("/");       
while(s.hasNext())
    xyz = s.next();
```

Comment: my code snippets work with "test/abc"  and "abc"

Comment: path will be changed like some times "test/abc" or just like "abc"..               String path = "test/abc/xyz"; 
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(path, "/");
while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
    ---- here how can i handle the last string? i don't know the last string what it is 
}

Comment: Try to explain your problem more. I don't get it. You will get the last string in the last run of this loop.

Comment: I am passing a string " /test/abc/..." like this way, but here i want to get the last  value or first value using stringtokenizer. In this case i am possible way to pas the string is "/test/abc/xyz", "test/abc" and "/test", these mentiones strings only i am able to pass.

Comment: Put the results into an array. LinkedList<String> components = new LinkedList<>();StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(path, "/");while (st.hasMoreElements())components.add((String) st.nextElement()); And you can get whatever value u like. components.getFirst();components.getLast();

Answer (score 1):

You could use [the `Path` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) to do it in a way that is platform independent:

```
String input = "/test/abc/xyz";
Path path = Paths.get(input);
String last = path.getFileName().toString(); //xyz
```

This will also work with `test/abc` or `abc`.